# Splitting up input based on separators and storing the values

Tags: python

so I am new to Python. I was wondering how I could take something like

```
"James-Dean-Winchester"
```

or

```
"James:Dean:Winchester"
```

or simply

```
"James Dean Winchester"
```

and have python be able to see which format is which, split the input based on the format and then store it in variables to be modified later on. Could I somehow store the splitting characters (":","-"," ") in an array then call the array on the text that I am wishing to split or is there an easier way of doing it?

Update: I should have added that there will only ever be one type of separator.

Comment: How's python supposed to know the format of your data? What if it's something like `"foo-bar:hello world"`?

Comment: Use `mystring.split(separator)` to split up the string based on separators. To check which separator is used, you could iterate through your separator array, calling `if separator in string:` (assuming there will only ever be one separator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could define a function that performs the split and returns the separator in addition to the separated array:

```
def multiSepSplit(string,separators=["-",":"," "]):
    return max([(string.split(sep),sep) for sep in separators],key=lambda s:len(s[0]))

multiSepSplit("James-Dean-Winchester")
# (['James', 'Dean', 'Winchester'], '-')

multiSepSplit("James Dean Winchester")
# (['James', 'Dean', 'Winchester'], ' ')

multiSepSplit("James:Dean:Winchester")
# (['James', 'Dean', 'Winchester'], ':')
```

How it works is by performing all the splits using a list comprehension on the separators and taking the one with the maximum number of elements in the resulting array.

Each entry in the list is actually a tuple with the resulting array s[0] and the separator that was used s[1].

Comment: Thanks! thats working for me, no issues. How do I go about storing each portion of the name as a variable? Like how do I access array s[0] and retrieve and store the first name, middle name and last name?

Comment: [ first,middle,last ],separator = multiSepSplit("James Dean Winchester")

Answer (score 0):

If you do not know which delimiter is in play for each string, you need to write some logic for this.

One suggestion is to maintain a list of potential delimiters (sorted by preference / popularity) and test whether they occur in your string more than once.

Below is an example.

```
delimiters = list('-: ')

test_list = ['James-Dean-Winchester', 'April:May:June',
             'John Abraham Smith', 'Joe:Ambiguous-Connor']

def get_delimiter(x, delim):
    for sep in delim:
        if x.count(sep) > 1:
            return sep
    else:
        return None

result = [get_delimiter(i, delimiters) for i in test_list]

# ['-', ':', ' ', None]
```

You can then link `test_list` with `result` via `zip`, i.e. by iterating indices in each list sequentially.

You can split a string by a delimiter using, for example, `'mystr1-mystr2-mystr3'.split('-')`.